# Why didn't others steal Yondu's fins?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol. 2,

> Yondu has at least 3 fins, including the one that Nebula shot off, the prototype with which he was cremated, and the one that was given to Kraglin after Yondu died. If these three existed, no doubt Yondu also had others.

**Where did Yondu get his fins? And why didn't other crew members steal them?**

Comment: Maybe they assumed it was part of his head.  I know I did.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Where did Yondu get his fins?**

Since the [Yaka Arrow](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Yaka_Arrow) is Centaurian in origin, I think it can be assumed that Centaurians design and build the fins. Since Yondu is the only Centaurian we've seen he either had backups, or the new prototype was one of his own design.

**And why didn't other crew members steal them?**

As we see with Kraglin, it takes time to learn how to master the arrow. And I'm sure Yondu isn't above killing whomever tries to steal it. And because it is challenging to learn, maybe most people don't want to bother.

I heard it said once:

`Ancient weapons and hokey religions are no match for a good blaster at your side.` - source unknown

Comment: Are you intentionally being facetious with the source of that quote?

Comment: @onewho I saw this in a movie about a bus that had to **speed** around the city, keeping its **speed** over fifty, and if its **speed** dropped, the bus would explode! I think it was called "The Bus That Couldn't Slow Down."

Comment: Well played sir.

Comment: Hmm. I thought it might have come from one of the recent Chinese Space Opera shows/films -- sounds rather like ancient **[Han](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Chinese)** philosophy, to me.